# How to deserialize and parse JSON data to get particular values from the response

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest

my http response is as shown:

```
{"controllerValues":{},"defaultValue":null,"eTag":"31935b5a76250197159c64a2a9ec8353","url":"/services/data/v43.0/ui-api/object-info/Opportunity/picklist-values/0126F0000022ATfQAM/StageName","values":[{"attributes":{"closed":true,"defaultProbability":100.0,"forecastCategoryName":"Closed","picklistAtrributesValueType":"OpportunityStage","won":true},"label":"Closed Won","validFor":[],"value":"Closed Won"},{"attributes":{"closed":false,"defaultProbability":5.0,"forecastCategoryName":"Pipeline","picklistAtrributesValueType":"OpportunityStage","won":false},"label":"Personal Details","validFor":[],"value":"Personal Details"},{"attributes":{"closed":false,"defaultProbability":15.0,"forecastCategoryName":"Pipeline","picklistAtrributesValueType":"OpportunityStage","won":false},"label":"Add Products","validFor":[],"value":"Add Products"},{"attributes":{"closed":false,"defaultProbability":25.0,"forecastCategoryName":"Pipeline","picklistAtrributesValueType":"OpportunityStage","won":false},"label":"Add Schemes","validFor":[],"value":"Add Schemes"},{"attributes":{"closed":false,"defaultProbability":40.0,"forecastCategoryName":"Pipeline","picklistAtrributesValueType":"OpportunityStage","won":false},"label":"Bank Details","validFor":[],"value":"Bank Details"},{"attributes":{"closed":false,"defaultProbability":60.0,"forecastCategoryName":"Pipeline","picklistAtrributesValueType":"OpportunityStage","won":false},"label":"Verification","validFor":[],"value":"Verification"},{"attributes":{"closed":false,"defaultProbability":65.0,"forecastCategoryName":"Pipeline","picklistAtrributesValueType":"OpportunityStage","won":false},"label":"Documents Review","validFor":[],"value":"Documents Review"},{"attributes":{"closed":false,"defaultProbability":95.0,"forecastCategoryName":"Pipeline","picklistAtrributesValueType":"OpportunityStage","won":false},"label":"Credit Approval","validFor":[],"value":"Credit Approval"},{"attributes":{"closed":false,"defaultProbability":90.0,"forecastCategoryName":"Pipeline","picklistAtrributesValueType":"OpportunityStage","won":false},"label":"Contract Signing","validFor":[],"value":"Contract Signing"}]}
```

how do i get all the value values?
I mean i need to get Add Products,Contact Signing,Bank details etc in a list in an apex class.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to parse JSON into a data structure accessible in Apex:

1. By parsing it into an untyped map of string to object properties OR
2. By parsing it into a specific set of Apex objects, which can be an object hierarchy.

[The documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) covers this adequately. Take a look at the JSON.deserializeUntyped and JSON.deserialize/deserializeStrict methods.